# How can I make it so the random number is changed every time it prints?

Tags: java, random

> Write the code to ask the user for a positive integer n, then print 10 random integers from 1 to n inclusive using `Math.random()`.

How do I make it so that the output is different every time? As of now every output following the first one is exactly the same.

```
/* Lesson 8 Coding Activity Question 1 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import edhesive.testing.Math;

public class U2_L8_Activity_One{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    /* Write your code here */
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Enter a positive integer.");
  int n = scan.nextInt();

  double ran = Math.random();
  int range = n;
  int min = 1;
  int answer = (int) (ran * range) + min;
  
  System.out.println("Printing 10 random integers from 1 to n...");
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  System.out.println(answer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Time to start working with loops in this code

Answer (score 1):

You properly generate a random number, but then just print it out ten times. If you want ten different numbers, you need to regenerate the number each time. E.g.:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    double ran = Math.random();
    int answer = (int) (ran * range) + min;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Math.random() method every time you want a random number. You are calling it once and assigning the result to a variable. Calling a `System.out.println` to print the variable will not change the result, because there is no reassignment of the variable you're printing.

Go with

```
System.out.println("The random number is " + Math.random());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer.");
    int max = scan.nextInt();

    int min = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int ran = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

        System.out.println(ran);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This Will work when exciuted, and its done in a simple manner such as what you provided

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import edhesive.testing.Math;

public class U2_L8_Activity_One{
  public static void main(String[] args){

System.out.println("Please enter a integer");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
double ran = Math.random();
int min = 1;
int  answer = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer1 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer2 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer3 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer4 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer5 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer6 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer7 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer8 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;
int  answer9 = (int) (Math.random() * n) + min;


System.out.println(answer);
System.out.println(answer1);
System.out.println(answer2);
System.out.println(answer3);
System.out.println(answer4);
System.out.println(answer5);
System.out.println(answer6);
System.out.println(answer7);
System.out.println(answer8);
System.out.println(answer9);


  }
}
```